# Execution failed for task ':cinteropAFNetworkingIOS'. > Cannot perform cinterop processing for AFNetworking: cannot determine headers location

Tags: kotlin, afnetworking, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

This error pops up in Xcode after a gradle build

[image]

or like the one below in your intelliJ

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you come across an error like this,

This property is used to replace the default Kotlin/Native compiler used by the Gradle plugin with a local distribution. Since this sample is included in the K/N repo, it has this property specified to use a compiler built from sources.

So you may just remove `org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.home` from your `gradle.properties` and rerun the build.

And for the error in the second image, you can ignore that because when you try to perform ./gradlew build in the terminal, this is bound to occurs as this is not handled by the gradle in IntelliJ or Android Studio. It will be recognized by the Xcode when you follow the Readme.md(https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/cocoapods) and unlink the "Pods_ios_app.framework" and re-link by browsing again to make it work.